# How can I solve a matrix $x^\top\!Mx=0$ with a better method?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

> I want to solve a matrix $x^\top\!Mx=0$ as follows,
>   $$
> x^\top\begin{bmatrix}
> O_{3\times3} & A \\
> B & C
> \end{bmatrix}x=0
> $$

---

In addition, there is a property of matrix $A$ and $B$, i.e. $A^\top\!B=I$.

I want to know a better method to solve $M$ using $A^\top\!B=I$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume A is a $3\times k$ matrix and B is a $k\times 3$ matrix.

Since $A^TB=I$, A and B has same number of rows so that both A and B are $3 \times 3$ square matrices too.
u'
Let $x^T=(u^T, v^T)$ we have $u^TAv+v^TBu+v^TCv=0$ or $u^T(A+B)v+v^TCv=0$ since $v^TBu=u^TBv$ (it is a $1\times 1$ matrix).

So for any vector v, as soon as $(A+B)v \ne 0$, we could find infinite number of u so that $u^T (A+B)v =-v^TCv$.
If $v^TCv=0$, we should choose any u which is perpendicular to (A+B)v.
If $v^TCv \ne 0$, choose any w which is not perpendicular to (A+B)v,
    calculate $s= w^T (A+B)v \ne 0$, let $u=\frac{-v^TCv}{s}w$

Comment: Sorry about the mistake with my question. Actually, the $x$ on the left and right side of $M$ is different. So I can not use $u^\top(A+B)v+v^\top\!Cv=0$ to solve this problem.